# Why dynamic equilibrium exists?

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, equilibrium

We know that at equilibrium Gibbs energy is minimum. We also know that at equilibrium both forward and reverse reactions occur simultaneously, and also we know that for a reaction to be spontaneous Gibbs energy should decrease in that direction. So if at equilibrium we have minimum Gibbs energy then both forward and backward reactions will be non spontaneous, since they are characterised by increase in Gibbs energy,therefore there should no forward and backward reactions and hence no dynamic equilibrium. Then why does [dynamic equilibrium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_equilibrium) exist?

Comment: Or you have reached the point where the net of the backwards and forwards reactions is zero. That is, you are at an equilibrium point between the two. Your mistake is in thinking that then the Gibbs free energy needs to increase.

Comment: Crossposted from http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/42906/7890

Comment: And crossposted under a different name. Bad form.